# Compiling SDL2 with mingw using sublime text 2 errors

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl, linker-errors

I am trying to compile SDL2 with mingw and I get this error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(main.
o): In function `main':   
e:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src
/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I googled this error and it looks like I need to specify to link with the `-mwindows` tag but that doesn't work. Here is my batch file:

```
g++ -o Game.exe Main/Main.cpp -lmingw32 -LC:\MinGw\include\SDL2\lib\x86 -mwindows -lSDL2main -lSDL2
pause
start /d "C:\Users\Mathew Bergen\Documents\Programming\C++\LD Practice" Game.exe
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Sorry, the it didn't format properly.

Comment: What does Sublime Text have to do with this linker error? Are you just saying that you're running the batch file using ST2's build system?

Comment: No, there is no relevance. I am running this batch file to compile the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char** agv){
    //code here
}
```

For your main function, most of the time I've seen that link error this was the problem. I know I'm really late at posting an answer it's just for other people who have the same problem and stumble upon this page

Comment: I can't be sure this is the problem because I can't see your main function, but it probably is the answer